# read Routing Table of default gateway?

Tags: bash, routes, ip

In bash, if I do `netstat -r -n` or `route -n` I see informations about routing table of IP kernel.
I'm interested to read routing table of my default gateway, the router from which I'm connected.
Is there a way to get this info?

Comment: This is not a programming question, this is much more applicable at Unix StackExchange or ServerFault StackExchange

Comment: Yes, this more a system question. The answer may involve SNMP, though. Something like this? https://serverfault.com/questions/41842/snmp-equivalent-for-show-ip-route